# Modal segue to show tab bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on an iPhone app whose main navigation happens through a tab bar. However, it opens with a welcome screen that does not show the tab bar, but rather has two buttons to go to the two most common tabs. One goes to the first tab, so in my storyboard I added a segue to the main tab bar controller. This works great.

But the second button goes to the third tab, so I added a segue directly to that screen in my storyboard. This results in the tab bar not being shown. All my research into this has been obfuscated by the dozens of people who want to *retain* the tab bar, not create it, so I'm a bit lost on what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second button, you should also segue to your tabBarViewController and call

```
[self setSelectedIndex:2]; // If you want to show the third tab
```

in viewWillApear method in your tabBarViewController

If you are using storyboard segue,
add this method in your first View Controller

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueName"])
    {
        MyTabBarVC *destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationVC.selectedIndex = myIndex; 
        // myIndex's value depends on which button you pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't that cause the third tab to be selected for the first button too? How do I differentiate between `viewWillAppear` being called from the first button and from the second?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. You can add a property to indicate which index you want to go to in your tabbarcontroller